# What are the arguments to IO::Pipe constructors in Perl?

Tags: perl

What are the arguments used in `IO::Pipe` perl constructors?

What I see in documentation is:

> IO::Pipe::new optionally takes two arguments, which should be objects blessed into IO::Handle, or a subclass thereof. These two objects will be used for the system call to pipe. If no arguments are given then method handles is called on the new IO::Pipe object.

I don't really get what it means. Can someone provide an example/explanation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's straight-forward once you learn object-oriented programming. See the Stack Overflow archive for recommendations of appropriate teaching material. To follow the explanation below, you need to keep in mind that `bless` works not only on hashrefs.

You should also already completely understand what the underlying [`pipe`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/pipe.2.html) POSIX system call does, and what a file descriptor is in C and Perl and what all sort of things it can point to, and how a FD is passed around in Perl as a glob. If these pieces are confusing, too, open separate questions and reference this one.

```
use IO::Pipe qw();
my $pipe = IO::Pipe->new($reader, $writer);
```

**tl;dr** version: `$reader` and `$writer` are expected to be file handles you or something else has opened earlier, most likely from the `open` function or a [`IO::File`](http://p3rl.org/IO%3a%3aFile) instance. The documentation mentions IO::Handle foremost because likely you want to also pipe FDs that are not proper files, but standard streams (STDIN, STDOUT) connected to certain processes, and for this purpose IO::Handle suffices.

---

**Detailed** version:

The `$reader` and `$writer` variables are expected to contain object instances of type `IO::Handle` (`$reader` is-a `IO::Handle`). `IO::Handle` is rarely used, more often its subclass `IO::File`.

```
use IO::File qw();
my $reader = IO::File->new('/usr/src/linux/COPYING', 'r');
# bless(*Symbol::GEN0 => 'IO::File')
$reader->fileno
# 6
$reader->can('getline')
# true

use IO::File::WithPath qw();
my $writer = IO::File::WithPath->new('/tmp/foobar', 'w');
$writer->fileno
# 7
$writer->can('print')
# true
```

For historical reasons, a lot of things that are not strict subclasses of IO::Handle work, too. It suffices that they merely behave like IO::Handle ("duck type"), i.e. provide some of the methods mentioned in the documentation, and those need not be inherited from IO::Handle.

```
open my $other_reader, '<', '/usr/src/linux/COPYING';
# \*{'::$other_reader'}
$other_reader->fileno;
# 8
$other_reader->can('getline');
# false, but works anyway, see http://p3rl.org/IO::Handle#BUGS

use File::Temp qw(tempfile);
my ($other_writer) = tempfile;
# \*{'File::Temp::$fh'}
$other_writer->fileno;
# 9
$other_writer->can('print')
# false, but works anyway, see http://p3rl.org/IO::Handle#BUGS

use IO::String qw();
my $s = IO::String->new("foo\nbar\nbaz");
# bless(*Symbol::GEN1 => 'IO::String')
$s->fileno
# undef
$s->can('getline')
# true

### TODO
use File::Map qw(map_handle);
map_handle my $map, '/boot/vmlinuz';  # ???

### TODO   some popen examples
```

Comment: This is an excellent answer, thanks. I do know how perl objects work, but the exact wordings of this manual were somehow unclear for me. Once I have more time, I will read it through and hopefully accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

See `man 3p pipe`:

> The pipe() function shall create a pipe and place two file 
>   descriptors, one  each  into the arguments fildes[0] and fildes[1],
>   that refer to the open file descriptions for the read and write ends
>   of  the  pipe.

Try it to see.

Comment: děkuju za odpověď a zdravím. :-)